# Metro app - how to update live tile when using javascript/html?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm just getting started on Metro app development using HTML, JS, & CSS. Is it possible to update the live tile with some data retrieved thru a WCF service? I don't see a "Add Service Reference" option when I right-click on References in Visual Studio 2012. This whole Metro app thing is pretty confusing. Can I use a combination of HTML/JS/CSS *and* C# (like ASP.NET) in a Metro app?

Here's what I'm trying to do - when the app is launched, it should open a webpage in an iframe within the app. I also want to read the logged-on user's account name (Windows authentication), fire off a call to a WCF service, get some data and display it on the tile, refreshed periodically. It sounds like I need a combination of HTML/JS and also C#.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Periodic notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150587.aspx) seem to fit your scenario perfectly.  With periodic tile updates, Windows will automatically update an app tile with the XML tile notification content hosted at a web address.  The web content can be served by a WCF service, or any other web server.

Code showing how an app can set up periodic updates using [startPeriodicUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701694.aspx):

```
var tileUpdater = Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication();
var interval = Windows.UI.Notifications.PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.halfHour;

// Every 30 minutes, Windows will update the tile with the content at 'uri'.
tileUpdater.startPeriodicUpdate(uri, interval);
```

If multiple updates should be downloaded to use [tile notification cycling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779724.aspx#cycling_tile_notifications), use [startPeriodicUpdateBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967946.aspx).

Note: It is possible to have an app written in HTML, JS, & CSS consuming a C# library, but I don't believe it is needed in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've downloaded the sample and looked at the code. In my case, the WCF service needs the logged-in user's account name along with the domain name as parameters. Is it possible to retrieve those? Could you also point me to an article where I can use HTML, JS & CSS with C#? Thank you.

Comment: It is possible if you can embed the user's account name and domain into the URL passed to your WCF service.  Periodic notifications are not viable if the WCF service requires custom authentication, or if the data provided on tiles should not be publicly accessible - push notifications are geared for those scenarios.  As for consuming a C# client library from JS, here is documentation to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx

Comment: Can push notifications be sent to the tile periodically? Thanks for the link on using C# in JS, so this is where WinRT fits in!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465450.aspx" 
Sending a tile push notification - This functionality would not typically be implemented using JavaScript." Oh well.

Comment: Yes, they could be sent periodically.  However, when and how often push notifications are sent is completely up to the service pushing them.  It should be noted that while push notifications are more flexible, they are considerably more complex than periodic notifications.  This article discusses some of the differences between the various delivery methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx

Comment: A quick clarifying point: push notifications are sent from a web service to WNS (Windows Push Notifications Service) on behalf of an application, not by the client application itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll explore the links in detail.